# Android Picasso not loading all my images that I listed in my drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, image-processing, picasso

I have a problem with android picasso. Some images are not loading in my phone. It just display black page it differs from phone. Other phones load it all while others didn't load at all or some is missing.

I'm using adapter btw

Here's my adapter code

```
        package com.jc.jcpremiere;



import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        // Declare Variables
        Context context;
        int[] flag;
        String[] rank;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context,  int[] flag, String[] rank) {
            this.context = context;
            this.flag = flag;
            this.rank = rank;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return rank.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app3x, container, false);
            ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.items); // need this ImageView

            Picasso.with(context).load(flag[position]).resize(50, 50)
            .centerCrop().into(imgflag); // use ImageView
            //imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
            return itemView;
        }



        private ImageView findViewById(int items) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

        }
    }
```

Comment: better check logs as there might be exception.Possible reason being the heap memory of different devices is different.So a device with a bigger heap will load more images effectively.

Comment: how do i fix this? I might think so too. I bet on old model phones this will not run well. But how do i fix this issues btw these images are like 100-500KB

Comment: Already compressed the images, its like 100-300KB now. any more than that the images are ugly and pixelated